# Unsupported operation on Windows Phone for FontImage.createMaterial()

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the following code to set the back command on the Toolbar in a Form:

```
        Command back = new Command("Back") {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                 mainForm.showBack();
             }
        };

        Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Title"); // getTitleStyle();
        FontImage backIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_BACK, s);
        this.getToolbar().addCommandToLeftBar("", backIcon, back);
```

This works fine on iOS and Android, but on Windows Phone (Eumlator) I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported operation`. After doing some debugging in the C# code, I found that the Exception is thrown in `Font.derive()` that calls  `CodenameOneImplementation.deriveTrueTypeFont()`, which is aparently not implemented on Windows Phone.

Are Material icons simply not supported on the current Windows Phone port, or is there a workaroung for this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old Windows Phone port doesn't support a great deal of functionality including icon fonts.

We are working on a completely [new ground up port](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/windows-phone-8-1-uwp-support.html) that should support everything.

Notice that icon fonts do work in the JavaScript port and you should be able to deploy that everywhere.

Comment: After playing around with it a bit more, I have noticed that. Thank you, then I will wait for the new Windows port and try the JavaScript port in the meantime.